# How do you do a bulk insert into Postgres from Chapel?

Tags: postgresql, chapel

I'm using the [CDO Library](https://github.com/marcoscleison/cdo) to insert data into Postgres.  This example fails;

```
use Postgres,
    LinearAlgebra;

const DB_HOST="localhost",
      DB_USER="buddha",
      DB_NAME="buddha",
      DB_PWD="buddha";

var q = "INSERT INTO r.condition_w (from_fid, to_fid, w) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);";
var con = PgConnectionFactory(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, database=DB_NAME, passwd=DB_PWD);
var cursor = con.cursor();    

var e = ((1 ,4, 7.2), (3, 7, 22.8));
writeln("e.size: ", e.size);
for i in 1..e.size {
  const r = e(i);
  cursor.execute(q, r);
}
```

It works okay if I have

```
var e = (1 ,4, 7.2);
```

Comment: When "e = (1, 4, 7,2)", you are calling execute with a single integer or real at a time. Does that actually work the way you want it to?

Comment: Also, could you mention more about the failure? Does it fail to compile, or is the data in the table incorrect?